# Hotkey for this application?

Tags: windows, autoit, hotkeys

I'm putting together an AutoIt script to automate notepad and this software called Ecsow Dialer. I'm stuck on one thing, that's trying to find the hot key to select the text box so it's ready to type text in. Manually you'd just press enter and it will open, but sometimes pressing enter will open up the menu along the top of the window, i think it all depends on where the cursor is in the window. I took a couple of screen shots, here they are below:

The red part is where i need it to select, when you press enter, it opens it up ready for text input:

[image: Before Pressing Enter]

and here is what happens when you press enter sometimes, sometimes it opens the menu above, this is why i need a hot-key instead of just having autoit press enter.

[image: After Pressing Enter]

If anyone can help me out, i'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the _GUICtrlListView* functions (they are user defined functions, meaning they can interact with outside programs as well in many cases)?

I'm not sure that's a standard window, if the AutoItInfo.exe tool doesn't provide a classid/classnamenn you are probably dealing with a non-windows-standard GUI.

If that's the case, try out [IUIAutomation](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/), they've done a good job with their tool helping others automate past AutoIt's standard functions.